# Recycle javaw.exe memory without killing the process

Tags: memory-management, arcgis-server, javaw

We have an application which we cannot change (we did not develop it). Thw applicationon Windows Server 2008 64bit runs a javaw.exe process that takes over time 9 GB of memory. We would like to know, if there is a possibility to recycle the process withoit killing/ terminating it?

Is there maybe an option when it is being utilized that it recycles itself (empties utilized memory) after a certain period?

We notice that when we restart it, it it way smaller.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

The Javaw process might be connected to others using sockets or IPC. killing it might ends thoses connections. The application might not appreciate to restart the process without any drawbacks.
Sometime, java process increase because of the -Xmx parameter and the usage of the max memory.
Some tuning could preharps be done on the garbage collection with performance impacts, to more frequenlty garbage collect the memory and not reach the 9gb size.
I don't know if the javaprocess could reduce the System allocated memory.

hope this help